# WCF Json serialization with service reference not updated

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, serialization

We facing a serious issue, but before saying that it's a bug in .net, I'd like to know if someone understand what's happening and why.

That's our configuration :
1 project DAL
1 project proxy 
many others project that use DAL with WCF services as well.
They communicate with wcf services.

We have added some properties in one object in the DAL 
We havn't updated service references in the proxy project.

(1)In the proxy with a breakpoint, we can see everything is retrieved properly except of course the new properties (service reference not updated => nothing abnormal)

The proxy is returning a JSON with WebMessageFormat.JSON ( we using the default provided serialization)

The response of the method called in proxy that call the (1) one in DAL is empty.

So it's definitely a problem in the JSON serialization ? no ?

Worst, we decided to changed from WebMessageFormat.JSON to WebMessageFormat.XML to see if the same happened, ==> It didn't

Last thing, no problem with other projects that hadn't been updated (they not using JSON ser)

Does someone have faced the same issue, or know why this is happening ?

Any help would be really nice :)

Thanks in advance to everyone and sorry for my english.

Comment: To get help you with your issue, you should post some code - the relevant part of your service and web.config could be interesting. What does "empty" mean? a null reference? Also, I am having some trouble understanding what you have done with the generated client proxy. Did you re-generate it, or you don't want to/can't re-generate it, for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is not a definite answer, but a suspicion. However, this was too much to include as a comment.)

Note: I am assuming the following from your question (please correct/clarify if wrong).

- The proxy project calls DAL through WCF and not the other way around. This would explain (1), and properties not updated through each layer.
- A client calls the proxy project, which exposes itself through WCF too (this would explain the proxy project returning a WebMessageFormat.JSON response)

The issue here may be, as you say, with the serialization of the proxy response itself. While it's always advisable that you update your project references, in such a case it is possible that the generated classes are not mapping exactly to the response that they describe.

My take so far is that the changes in the classes had changed the internal responses in such a way that the references can no longer be mapped correctly to the response type, which is likely the ones from the mapped classes. The XML serializer is likely a separate implementation of the serializer, so it is likely that the JSON serializer has the problem failing on this specific case. You could check if this is the case by checking if there are any `first chance exception` in your internal output, or by adding debugging outside of your own code. This would likely confirm that the JSON serialization is facing an issue.

It may be actually be a bug, or an unsupported scenario when properties to map are not present.

Comment: After trying many scenarios, we arrived at the same conclusion... this is an unsupported scenario. Thank for your help and for trying to bring an answer to that. In debug mode, the response from wcf is ok, and crash before returning the JSON in the other wcf. Definitely a problem with the JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you use the DataContractSerializer with JSON if you are going to be consuming serialized JSON data from WCF (Set up your data contracts of course). I've ran into a few problems with JSON serializer, and realized it's a bit iffy with .NET

Another solution is to use this JSON serializer with .NET:
http://james.newtonking.com/json

Answer (score 0):

Do you have object of type date or any other non primitive data type in the response data, I have faced problem when i try to include date object in the response data, for a quick work around I changed the 
data type to string, it worked for me.